# Cargar Dataframe en segundo plano

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Tengo una pequeña herramienta realizada en pthon 3.6 en la que utilizo pandas para cargar dataframes. Quiero cargar un archivo .xlsx muy grande, con unos 200.000 registros y utilizo `file = pd.read_excel('archivo.xlsx')`

Esto tarda mucho y me deja la herramienta bloqueada unos 20 o 30 segundos, hay alguna manera de lanzar ese proceso en segundo plano cuando arranque la herramienta y que cuando necesite utilizar ese dataframe ya esté cargado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lanzar un hilo para que en él se cargue el dataframe. Necesitarás cargarlo a una variable global para que sea accesible desde el programa principal.

El siguiente código puede servirte como "esqueleto básico". He simulado los tiempos de carga mediante `sleep()`, pues el dataframe que he cargado ([obtenido de aquí](https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/) se carga demasiado rápido.

```
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

# url = "http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip"
url = "FL_insurance_sample.csv"

df = None

def cargar_dataframe(filename):
    global df
    print("Inicio la carga del dataframe {}".format(filename))
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # Hagamos que espere 2 segundos más
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Terminé la carga del dataframe")


def main():
    print("Arrancado programa principal")
    t = threading.Thread(target=cargar_dataframe, args=(url,))
    t.start()
    print("El programa principal tarda 5 segundos en iniciarse")
    for i in range(5):
        print("Quedan {}s en el programa principal".format(5-i))
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Programa principal inicializado. Esperando por dataframe")
    t.join()
    print("Dataframe disponible")
    print(df.head())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

El programa principal crea un hilo en el que ejecutar la función `cargar_dataframe` y lo arranca. Después se dedica a sus cosas (en este caso un bucle que va imprimiendo un mensaje cada segundo), y después espera (mediante `t.join()`) a que el hilo finalice. En este ejemplo el dataframe carga antes de que el programa principal haya llegado al `join()` por lo que para cuando el programa principal llegue, no tendrá que esperar (`t.join()` retornará inmediatamente). Como prueba de que el dataframe ha sido leido, lo imprimo.

Esto es lo que sale al ejecutarlo:

```html
Arrancado programa principal
Inicio la carga del dataframe FL_insurance_sample.csv
El programa principal tarda 5 segundos en iniciarse
Quedan 5s en el programa principal
Quedan 4s en el programa principal
Quedan 3s en el programa principal
Terminé la carga del dataframe
Quedan 2s en el programa principal
Quedan 1s en el programa principal
Programa principal inicializado. Esperando por dataframe
Dataframe disponible
   policyID statecode       county  eq_site_limit        ...          point_longitude         line  construction  point_granularity
0    119736        FL  CLAY COUNTY       498960.0        ...               -81.711777  Residential       Masonry                  1
1    448094        FL  CLAY COUNTY      1322376.3        ...               -81.707664  Residential       Masonry                  3
2    206893        FL  CLAY COUNTY       190724.4        ...               -81.700455  Residential          Wood                  1
3    333743        FL  CLAY COUNTY            0.0        ...               -81.707703  Residential          Wood                  3
4    172534        FL  CLAY COUNTY            0.0        ...               -81.702675  Residential          Wood                  1

[5 rows x 18 columns]
```

**Notas**

El uso de hilos en Python no suele mejorar los tiempos de ejecución si el problema es un uso intensivo de la CPU, ya que debido a la existencia de un *lock global* (el GIL), los hilos se van turnando al ejecutar instrucciones y no pueden ejecutarse dos instrucciones a la vez, ni aún si dispusieras de varias CPUs (cores).

Sin embargo, si el problema es de entrada/salida, un hilo puede estar esperando datos del disco y mientras tanto otro puede usar la CPU. Aquí sí se notaría mejora de velocidad. También si lo que ejecuta uno de los hilos es una extensión python escrita en C, pues en este caso la extensión no usa el GIL y sí que puede ejecutarse en paralelo al otro hilo que use python puro. En este caso también es aplicable, pues muchas partes de Pandas están escritas en C, probablemente la que lee CSV es una de ellas.

Por tanto cabe esperar una mejora con esta estrategia.

He leído muchas veces por internet que si los hilos no te dan mejoras de velocidad, uses en su lugar procesos (módulo `multiprocessing`). En teoría el consejo es bueno, puesto que los procesos no comparten memoria, y por tanto no interfieren con el GIL, y así se podrían usar varios cores. Sin embargo no creo que para este caso fuese apropiado, pues precisamente por no compartir memoria, no podrías hacer que pandas lea el csv en un proceso pero lo deje en una variable del otro proceso. El módulo `multiprocessing` se ocupa de comunicar entre sí los procesos, vía sockets, y con conversiones intermedias al formato pickle. Esto sería tremendamente ineficiente en este caso pues, como tú especificas, el dataframe a transferir es muy grande.

Comment: Muchas gracias es justo lo que buscaba